# prevent overlapping output when using 'RefreshView'

Tags: c#, maui

learning Maui ... I'm using in 'MainPage.xaml', a 'RefreshView' with action 'Button(s)'. Obviously, 'RefreshView' when within a 'VerticalStack', has some known issue(s). Without the 'VerticalStack', however, the 'Buttons' overlap the 'Refresh' content!

Question: how could I separate the Buttons from the RefreshView (or, not using 'RefreshView' at all!)?

Ideally, I would like to put the Button(s) in a Flyout menu OR Tabs i.e. any solution using 'Shell mixed Navigation'.
(But, I'm not succeeding ... in any trial: Button > Command="{Binding VARhCommand}" set in 'HikeViewModel.cs', fails!)

You can check the App in GIT: https://github.com/edikaufmann/HikeGIT.

Confessing that I'm not a Maui wizard - what would be the most obvious solution?

Comment: Please read [ask] before posting.  Instead of describing your code, please post the relevant code, properly formatted, in your question.  Simply including a link to a repo is against the site guidelines

Comment: sorry, Iddn't want to break rules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your needs, you can use other views except for not using `VerticalStackLayout` outside of `RefreshView`.

If you use `Grid`, you can set the `Rows` and `columns` for your views inside your Grid. That way it doesn't lead to the overlapping problem you're talking about.

The following XAML shows how to create a Grid with three rows and two columns:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="GridDemos.Views.XAML.BasicGridPage"
             Title="Basic Grid demo">
   <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="100" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        ...
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

For more information about `Grid`, you can check document: [Grid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/layouts/grid).

Answer (score 0):

First, I would use the Grid, instead of Stack layout.

Second, if we see how the grid is defined in your code:

```
<Grid>
```

It does not contain Column/Row Definitions.

Third, if we take this part of your code for example:

```
<VerticalStackLayout Grid.Row="1"
                             Grid.Column="0"
                             WidthRequest="220">
            <Button x:Name="button1"
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    Grid.Column="3"...
```

We do not really have to specify `Grid.Row` second time.

Start by fixing the outermost Grid. Remove the StacksLayouts for now, and place everything using that grid.